# How do I ensure data binding occurs after view model has been constructed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am encountering a major gotcha when using the MVVM architecture and I haven't seen it directly addressed or even mentioned. In a multi-threaded application, it's possible for a view to start databinding before the View Model is fully constructed, creating binding failures.

Here's is an example:

```
public class StocksViewModel
{

    // blah blah

    public IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AvailableStocks
    {
        get
        {
            // This could take a minute or two
            return StockService.GetAvailableStocks(User);
        }
    }

    public double Quantity
    {
        get => Quantity;
        set
        {
            Quantity = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Quantity));
        }
    }

    public double Symbol
    {
        get => Symbol;
        set
        {
            Symbol = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Symbol));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's theXAML:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="Quantity"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" SelectedValue="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.Quantity}"  DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.AvailableStocks}"   />

        <ComboBox x:Name="Symbol"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" SelectedValue="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay, Path=ViewModel.Symbol}"  DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.AvailableStocks}"   />
```

As you can see, the databinding can be unpredictable. If the StockService takes several seconds, the Quantity and Symbol will never get a chance to data-bind to AvailableStock.

What's the prescribed method for handling this situation?

Comment: How is Quantity and Symbol related to the AvailableStocks property...? The binding to the Quantity and Symbol properties till be refreshed whenever the properties are set so I don't really understand your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this would be to take a different path than you have here. In the constructor for my view model, I would create a `readonly ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. I would also kick off a new thread to call `GetAvailableStocks` at that time. When the result returns, you can populate the `ObservableCollection`. However, while the data is being retrieved, I would include a loading icon or a similar idea so the user is aware we are still gathering results.

A view model should load all the data it can and be ready to display additional data whenever it is received. If the data could be preloaded and passed into the view model, that would be even better but this can't always occur.

A code sample (excuse my formatting as I'm on mobile):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _availableStocks;

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AvailableStocks 
    {
        get => _availableStocks;
    }
    public bool IsExecuting { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _availableStocks = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        IsExecuting = true;
        TaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var results = StockService.GetAvailableStocks(User);
            foreach (var stock in results)
                AvailableStocks.Add(stock);
            IsExecuting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is untested but I hope it will help you with your issue!

Comment: You are awesome with the sauce and no sauerkraut.  One last question, does any of the MVVM frameworks document this gotcha?  I've never seen it mentioned or addressed directly.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I don't believe I've seen this documented in any MVVM framework. Although, I'm not certain that I would even document it if I managed a framework. I think this might be more of a design pattern question as opposed to a framework question. However, I do see where you are coming from.

Comment: Yeah, but it's one of those issues that catches you by surprise, especially for a developer who doesn't grasp threading and lifetime.  Your solution is what I considered, but I always second guess myself.